# Select objects in an array with conditions and generated new array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data array like below. I want to select the object with x ===1 and name ==="Dog" then push them into a new array. arr2 is the result that I am expecting. Appreciate your help!

```
var arr1 = [         
             {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.7, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.7, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:3.1, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.7, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.6, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:3.0, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.9, x:2, name: "Dog"},

             {y:3.0, x:0.7, name: "Cat"},
             {y:3.0, x:0.7, name: "Cat"},
             {y:3.1, x:0.7, name: "Cat"},
             {y:3.0, x:0.7, name: "Cat"},
             {y:2.9, x:2.3, name: "Cat"},
             {y:2.8, x:2.3, name: "Cat"},
             {y:2.7, x:2.3, name: "Cat"},
             {y:2.8, x:2.3, name: "Cat"},

             {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.4, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:3.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.7, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.6, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.8, x:2, name: "Dog"},
             {y:2.9, x:2, name: "Dog"}
            ]

    var arr2 = [

                     {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:2.7, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:2.7, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:3.1, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:2.4, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:2.5, x:1, name: "Dog"},
                     {y:3.5, x:1, name: "Dog"}


]
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i].x === 1 && arr1[i].name === "Dog"){
    return ****;
    arr2.push(***)
  }
  }
```

Comment: What you want to do is exactly what [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for.

Comment: This should have been easy to get some direction by doing a web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
var arr2 = arr1.filter(function(item){
    return item.x === 1 && item.name === "Dog"
});
```

In case `arr2` already exists then you can use array concatenation

```
arr2.concat(arr1.filter(function(item){
    return item.x === 1 && item.name === "Dog"
}));
```

For reference - [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I think he need to concat the results into array2. In case:
```arr2.concat(arr1.filter(function(item){
    return item.x === 1 && item.name === "Dog"
}));```

Comment: @ema - OP mentioned new array so that rules out the concatenation part.  However, as you have mentioned, I would be adding this too as part of solution